# Django forms two fields with same same value one being unique with default value and other being hidden field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model with two fields one unique uuid field and another urlfield

```
class Image(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4,unique=True)
```

I create a django model form

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    filename = forms.HiddenInput()

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = "__all__"
```

in the formview uuid field will be set automatically with a unique uuid, I want to set the filename with the same uuid automatically set to uuid field by default. How can i achieve this?

Comment: But there is no `filename` in your model?

Comment: no there is no file name in model, I want to assign the default value from model uuid field to form field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "*patch*" the `__init__` function, and set an `.initial` value for the given field, like:

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    filename = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['filename'].initial = self.instance.uuid

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried this method already, but HiddenInput field doesn't appear in self.fields of form class

Comment: @Harwee: hold on, you use a `HiddenInput`? That is not a field, that is a widget...

Comment: ah what a stupid mistake on my part, thanks for solving the issue.

Comment: Do you know whether I could do the same approach with drf serializers?